# How can i create download link using django?

Tags: python, django, url

I'm using my own project using django.
I'm trying to download file using django.
I finished upload file to using django.
but i don't know how to create file download link in django.
example) test.java , and my domain is example.com, port is 9001 and media folder is /media
i just want to down https://example.com:9001/media/test.java just like this.
I google all method but there's no clue..
here is my code.
view.py -> upload part

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'useraccount/index.html', {})

@csrf_exempt
def file_list(request):
    return render(request, 'useraccount/list.html', {})

@csrf_exempt
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('file_list')

    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'useraccount/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

upload.html

```
<html>
    <head><title>Upload Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload/"
              method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
            File:
            <input type="file"
                   name="file"
                   id="id_file" />
            <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

upload.html

```
{% extends 'useraccount/index.html' %}

{%  block content %}
    <h2>Upload file</h2>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Upload file</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

list.html

```
{% extends 'useraccount/index.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>The image has been uploaded!!</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import UploadFileModel

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadFileModel
        fields = {'title', 'file'}
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

  path('upload/', views.upload_file, name='upload_file'),
    path('list/', views.file_list, name='file_list'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

To download an image stored in database, it would be :

*Simple Example*

**views.py**

```py
def download_image(self, imageid):
    image = UploadFileModel.objects.get(pk=imageid)
    image_buffer = open(image.file.path, "rb").read()
    content_type = magic.from_buffer(image_buffer, mime=True)
    response = HttpResponse(image_buffer, content_type=content_type);
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(image.file.path)
    return response
```

**urls.py**

```py
path('downloadimage/<str:imageid>/$', views.download_image, name='download_image'),
```

**template.html**

```html
<a href="{% url 'useraccount:download_image' imageid=<id_of_image> %}" type="button">Download image</a>
```

> *Note:* Please replace `<id_of_image>` in template with image id required.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate `url` file by `url` methods like that:

in  .py:

```
my_file_field.url
```

in template:

```
<a href="{% my_file_field.url %}"> file link ! </a>
```

see django's doc  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/